# IIS 7.5 using 32 bit driver instead of 64 bit

Tags: mysql, iis, odbc, driver

I am using IIS 7.5 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine to connect to a MySQL server through ODBC driver 3.51.

When I developed the application in VS 2010, I created a 64 DSN (using c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) for the connection and everything was going great.

However when I have deployed the application on IIS, it is not using this DSN. So I created a 32 bit DSN.

Now I am facing the problem of **Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow** on every other page.

Please help. How can make IIS use 64 bit DSN that I created while developing the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `Enable 32 Bit Applications` setting of your websites Application Pool to switch between running your website in 32 or 64 Bit mode.

See [How to Enable a 32-bit Application Pool in IIS 7](http://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx) for details.

Comment: That is cool..!! IT exactly solved my problem... Thanks.. :-)